# Isn't SortedList supposed to be slower than Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Right now I am picking up c# and right now, I am trying to figure out possible performance issues with long lists. Therefore I wanted to have some figures as to how the speed differs when I am using Dictionaries or SortedLists.

Which is why I came up with this example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace dictionary_vs_sortedList
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        long search = 20000;
        SortedList<long, string> myList = new SortedList<long, string>();
        Dictionary<long, string> myDict = new Dictionary<long, string>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 10*search; i++){
            myDict.Add(i, "hi");
            myList.Add(i, "hey");

        }

        var watch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();



        if (myDict.ContainsKey(search))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is included");

        }

        watch1.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts1 = watch1.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(ts1);


        var watch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (myList.ContainsKey(search))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is also included");

        }
        watch2.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts2 = watch2.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(ts2);
    }
}
}
```

The output for this always gives me a longer running time for the Dictionary than for the SortedList. I thaught Contains() goes with O(1) for a Dictionary and with O(n) for a SortedList

**Edit:**

Thanks for the quick help. 
I wasn't paying attention, as to how my measurement may be compromised by lines of code I do not want to measure. 
This Question may now be closed.

Comment: What is a "longer runtime"? Just some miliseconds? Then it´s probably due to some initialization going on in front of your method. Apart from this I believe a `SortedList` also uses hashes to get O(1).

Comment: Do the benchmarking correctly, use this: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: The reason for this is that the first time you call `Console.WriteLine` some initialization is done, this takes up almost all the time you measure. You need to measure correctly.

Comment: According to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/sortedlist.cs,650e966119d0cc88), it uses binary search, so lookup is O(log n). The performance benefit is probably that `long` is fast to compare, and storing as an array gives high locality. But I'm surprised the `WriteLine` doesn't dominate the running time and render the exercise moot.

Comment: @Ðаn: of course it isn't a top concern, but since I may have to deal with large amounts of data, I might wanna get to know about it. Naturally, C# isn't my first programming language.

Comment: If you'd like the close the question, it is within your power to do so, @BaronFurzgesicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not just do one run to test the performance of an operation. I put an `for` loop with 1000 iterations around each check (and removed the `Console.Write`) and got following results

> ```
> Dictionary  00:00:00.0000286
> SortedList  00:00:00.0056493
> ```

So the result is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your time measurement:

- First, before you start measuring something you will have to execute that part first. The simple reason is that before the code is executed it must be compiled by the JIT-compiler. This takes time. You do not want that compile time being part of your measurement.
- Second, O(n) and O(1) operations based on a reasonably balanced filling. Furthermore, a search for one element can result in a different measurement than searching for another element in the same collection. I can thing of situations where a dictionary can perform very slow and a SortedList very vast. So you should do multiple searches (1000? 100.000?) with different (random?) values. Doing so will result in a more reliable result.
- Third, remove as much code out of the measurement as possible. The Console.WriteLine is a rather slow operation and will have a very negative impact on your measurement.

*** EDIT ***

The SortedList has a O(log n) operation, not O(n), but that is besides the point.

Comment: Big O *doesn't* measure averages. (That's theta, if memory serves, although I'm not positive.)  It measures performance *as the size of the problem set approaches infinity*, which of course means that for smaller sized problem sets it's not necessarily a useful metric.

Comment: @Servy I think he means average case in terms of the input problem. A O(n) algorithm can be O(1) for best case, for example.

Comment: @adjan But that's just it, big O *isn't* a measure of the average, given a possible range of outcomes.  There's a *different* function that's used for that.  Typically Big O is used to describe worst case performance, although you can use it to describe best case behavior or to include a range (as you gave an example of yourself).

Comment: @Servy: Not entirely true. Example: I create a List<int>, fill it with 10.000 items (0..9999) and call the Find-method to search it (an O(n) operation). Searching for 0 will immediately be found, like a O(1) operation. If I search for element 9999, it will "feel" like a true O(n) operation. If I look for element 5000, it will "feel" like a O(n/2) operation. The average of all elements would be O(n/2). But O(n/2) is mostly noted as O(n).

Comment: @Servy: But all of this is really not the point. The OP is measuring something and he is measuring wrong. That is the whole point. And he should use multiple values in multiple iterations to get correct measurements which will reflect the O(x or y) operation he is expecting.

Comment: @Servy But worst case lookup for a hash-table is O(n)

Comment: @MartinMulder That means that you applied Big O *to the average*.  That doesn't mean Big O *is* the average.  Big O is a function that considers the behavior of an operation *as the problem set approaches infinity*.  You can apply that function to best case, worst case, average case, some particular case, or *anything* else.  The fact that you specifically used Big O yourself to describe best case and worst case clearly shows that it doesn't inherently refer to the average case.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, that's a correct statement.  What's your point?

Comment: @Servy: If the big O typically describes the WORST case performance, than a Dictionary should also be described as a O(n), since I can create sitations with a Dictionary with many elements with the same hashcode but different values with will result in O(n) operations.

Comment: @MartinMulder Ineed, the worst case situation of a dictionary access *is* O(n).  Thus when people say that dictionary access is O(1) (if they want the statement to be correct) they'd need to qualify it by saying "assuming a reasonably balanced hash function".  (Many people omit that for brevity, as it's common enough knowledge.)  So here we have an example of using Big O to refer to something other than worst case.  I did say "typically" after all.  This is an example of a case that's not typical.  Also for insertions you'd need to qualify it as being an "amortized" cost.

Comment: @Servy: I assume you downvoted my question. Either way I have always been taught that if I tell somebody NO or he is doing something wrong, that I also should tell him what I expect, how to turn the NO in a YES, how do it correct. Please help me improve my answer.

Comment: @MartinMulder I've specifically told you what you've said is wrong, and what a correct version of that statement would be, so I'm not sure what else you're expecting of me.  That said, no, I'm not obligated to fix your answer for you, even though I *have* told you why it's wrong, and what a correct explanation of the relevant concept is.

Comment: @Servy My point is that when you talk about time complexity for data structures and algorithms in terms of big O notation you usually specify the average and not worst case. For example Quick sort as Θ(n log(n)) and not O(n^2) which is the worst case.

Comment: @Magnus And like I've said numerous times now, Big O isn't *inherently* about considering average case, or best case, or worst case, or anything like that.  You can apply it to *any* of them.  Saying that Big O *is* the average case (as the answer does) is simply wrong.  You certainly *can* apply it to the average case, but what you're applying *to* the average case (and what Big O actually *is*) is how the function performs as the problem space approaches infinity.

Comment: @Servy I think it was an accurate statement in the answer when he says that O(log n) for sortedList and O(1) for dictionary means the average case.

Comment: @Servy: Modified my answer. I must admit: you are not the most helpful, pleasant person I've met. As I said, perhaps that sentence was wrong, it was greatly outside the point: His measurements was wrong, not, the interpretation of O(x). Thanx anyway for your pleasant 'lessons'.

Comment: @Magnus Considering that neither of the values provided are the "average case" Big O for the respective operations, saying that the statement is accurate is just wrong.

Comment: @MartinMulder It's unfortunate that you don't care at all about making incorrect statements in your answer to other people's questions.  I can understand how someone who doesn't care at all about making correct statements might be bothered by someone informing them of the fact that their statements are incorrect, nonetheless, while *you* don't consider providing *accurate* answers helpful, I (and hopefully, most other people) *do*.  I find someone disregarding the accuracy of their answer as unpleasant as you apparently find me.

Comment: @Servy Aha, ok so what does in your opinion on `Avg: Search` for hash table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case mean? If not O(1).

Comment: @Magnus Whether it's O(1) or O(n) is dependant on the hash function.  If you have a good hash function it's O(1) if you have the worst hash function it's O(n).